# Machine instructions and memory address

Tags: memory, assembly, cpu, cpu-registers

This is actually a examination question, i have doubts , i need to know the correct answer and explanation.

Common Questions 1 and 2.

```
     INSTRUCTION                         INSTRUCTION SIZE (word)
    MOV R1 LOC1                            2
    MOV R2 #01                             1
    ADD R1 R2                              1
    MOV LOC2,R1                            2
    Halt                                   1
```

Q1. consider that the memory is byte addressable with size 32 bits , and the program has been loaded starting from memory location 1000 (decimal). CPU has been halted after executing the Halt instruction, the return address saved in the stack will be

a) 1007

b) 1020

c) 1024

d) 1028

// i know that during the execution of any instruction , Program Count (PC register), incremented.  so when halt instruction is executed , the PC value should be 1028 but correct ans is c) , i'm not sure. please help to find correct answer.

Q2. If CPU is 32 bit , word addressable , program is loaded form starting address 1000. If interrupt occurs during the ADD instruction, what will be the return address pushed on to the stack.

a) 1007

b) 1004

c) 1005

d) 1016

Comment: So what answers did you provide?  What is your reasoning?

Comment: for Q.1) two answer possible , during halt instruction if PC value incremented then , answer will be d) 1028 , if PC value doesn't increment then answer is going to be c) 1024.

Comment: (In fairness they did not specify this machine very well.  Some machines leave the PC incremented on an interrupt, while others back it up when an interrupt occurs.)

Comment: in q.1) cpu is byte addressable and starting address of the program is 1000, that is the initial value of PC register for this program. first MOV instruction will be fatched at address 1000, then during the execution of the instruction PC value will be incremented to 1000+8=1008 (instruction is 2 word long). Similarly , when value of PC is 1016 , the third MOV instruction will be fatched, between the execution of this instruction PC value will be increment to 1016+8=1024 , at this address we have next instruction to fatch that is halt instruciton.

Answer (score 2):

Correct answer for Q1 should be D. 1028. With 1024, after the interrupt control again comes to HALT and there will be no escape route. I don't know if any processor does this. Certainly not x86 architecture as shown here:
http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_134.html

Answer (score 1):

Its depend on what asked in question,

- If in question asked during the **HALT** instruction then PC value is the next instruction address because PC value is always next instruction.
  But
- If in question asked after execution of **HALT** instruction then PC value is **HALT** instruction starting address because after successful execution of HALT instruction we know that there is no next instruction so PC value override with HALT instruction starting address and then compiler return this address with exit point.

Answer (score 0):

As to Question 1 I woould say that it can not be answered without knowing which CPU it is.

For Q2 I would say that it doesn't matter. The CPU must take care that it stays in a consistent state, so each instruction must be atomic and non-interruptable.

Let's assume that the CPU is almost done with the instruction and the value is already assigned. If the interrupt occures and the address would be before the instruction it would be executed twice, which shouldn't happen as this would result in wrong code in such cases.

So if the instruction is taking place, the CPU must either cancel the instruction and the address would be before it, or it would have to finish the instruction and and the address would be after it. Either way, you wouldn't know the exact timing and thus you don't know the adress.

A definite answer should be only possible if looking into the hardware reference manual of the given CPU.

Answer (score 0):

HALT instruction is an unconditional branch inst which has target address same as that of HALT inst itself. So, when HALT inst is fetched, PC will be updated to contain 1028 but during execution of HALT inst, PC will be again updated(as HALT is a unconditional branch inst) to 1024.As the execution finishes, current value of PC i.e 1024 is pushed into stack.
Therefore (C) is correct choice.